# @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37 ERROR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, material-ui

I am facing an error while installing node_modules using this command

`npm install`

I am having npm=9.6.7 and node=18.17.1

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @emotion/core@10.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/core
npm ERR!     @emotion/core@"^10.0.9" from react-select@3.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-select
npm ERR!       react-select@"^3.1.0" from react-timezone-select@0.9.9
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-timezone-select
npm ERR!         react-timezone-select@"^0.9.9" from the root project
npm ERR!     @emotion/core@"^10.0.35" from react-spinners@0.10.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-spinners
npm ERR!       react-spinners@"^0.10.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   30 more (@material-ui/core, @material-ui/icons, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid
npm ERR!   @material-ui/data-grid@"^4.0.0-alpha.37" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from @material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.37
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/data-grid
npm ERR!     @material-ui/data-grid@"^4.0.0-alpha.37" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/abhinav/.npm/_logs/2023-08-19T12_06_08_721Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

I am not able to install node_modules and core files of react to run my project can anyone help in resolving this error
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates a dependency conflict. The @material-ui/data-grid package requires a peer dependency of react@^17.0.0.
You can find it here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/data-grid/v/4.0.0-alpha.35